# Get the latest log entry by group in Log Analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

I have a lot's of computer data in Log Analytics and I would like to have the latest heartbeat by computer name.

For example with this Custom Log:

| HistoryId | ComputerName | Heartbeat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DESKTOP-1 | 2020.02.01 23:32:31 |
| 2 | DESKTOP-2 | 2020.02.01 13:32:11 |
| 3 | DESKTOP-11 | 2020.02.01 22:32:00 |
| 4 | DESKTOP-2 | 2020.01.23 21:32:11 |
| 5 | DESKTOP-4 | 2020.02.01 22:32:11 |
| 6 | DESKTOP-2 | 2020.01.11 09:32:11 |

The result would be this:

DESKTOP-1: 2020.02.01 23:32:31

DESKTOP-2: 2020.02.01 13:32:11

DESKTOP-4: 2020.02.01 22:32:11

DESKTOP-11: 2020.02.01 22:32:00

I tought that *summarize* and *arg_max* maybe show me a direction but not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `summarize arg_max(Heartbeat, *) by ComputerName` should give you the desired result

```
datatable(Id:int, ComputerName:string, Heartbeat:datetime)
[
    1, 'DESKTOP-1', datetime(2020.02.01 23:32:31),
    2, 'DESKTOP-2', datetime(2020.02.01 13:32:11),
    3, 'DESKTOP-11',datetime(2020.02.01 22:32:00),
    4, 'DESKTOP-2', datetime(2020.01.23 21:32:11),
    5, 'DESKTOP-4', datetime(2020.02.01 22:32:11),
    6, 'DESKTOP-2', datetime(2020.01.11 09:32:11),
]
| summarize arg_max(Heartbeat, *) by ComputerName
```